# Apache Cordova - Hybrid Mobile Application page opening like a chrome browser not like cordova application

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I'm working on Cordova to develop the hybrid mobile application using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

How can we redirect from one page to other pages not like browser application, it must be Cordova application.

It is working good in a browser but if I generate the .apk file and deploy onto the mobile device it is working like web application not like Cordova application.
Here, I'm using coding like window.open(),window.location.href() and window.location.replace().

```
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btn4").click(function() {
                $lname = $("#lname").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/RESTfulDemoDerby/webresources/com.mss.mmxregistration/session',
                    data: {lname: $lname},
                    type: 'GET',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    ContentType: 'html/text',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    cache: false
            }).done(function(response) {

                   if (response== 'success') {
   window.location.href='http://localhost:8383/HTML5Application1/listform.html';
                   }
                    else {
                 window.location.replace("http://localhost:8383/HTML5Application1/login1.html");

                    }

             }).fail(function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //   alert(url);

                    alert(textStatus + " : " + errorThrown.toString());
                });
            });
        });
```

let me clarify doubt that can we can add a PhoneGap plugin to Cordova application? Because both are different platforms to develop the hybrid application using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Comment: cordova and phonegap are the same thing, you can use phonegap plugins on cordova projects. Do HTML5Application1/listform.html and HTML5Application1/login1.html exists inside your cordova www folder?

Comment: With Cordova and PhoneGap apps you **have** do wait for the `deviceready` event to fire, you can't use `$(document).ready` because Cordova isn't loaded yet when the document is ready.

Comment: @Timo, he has to wait for the deviceready if he want to use some plugin, but he isn't using any.

Comment: @VinodKumarMarupu, then replace the  window.location.replace("http://localhost:8383/HTML5Application1/login1.html"); to  window.location.replace("HTML5Application1/login1.html");

Answer (score 2):

You should take a deeper look into cordova/phonegap and the whole thing about this. The normal way for building an hybrid application with phonegap/cordova would be to set up a single-page-application.

That means, that you use a framework: For example - [jquery mobil](https://jquerymobile.com/)e. With help from this framework you're able to set up a single-page-application.

You can set up [persistent toolbars](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-fixed-persistent/) for example. After you did that you can navigate through the pages via a normal `<a href="#pageID">Page 2</a>` where `#pageID` has to be the id from the page you want to navigate to.

Single-Page Application Template would look like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-title="Page 1">
    <div class="content">
        <a href="#page2">Testcontent Page 2 - Go to Page 2</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-title="Page 2">
    <div class="content">
        <a href="#page1">Testcontent Page 2 - Back to Page 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

`data-title="Page 1"` is the title which will be automatically changed through JavaScript and [jQuery](https://jquery.com). It'll replace the `<h1></h1>` Tags content inside your persistent header.

Just Google for Single Page Application Cordova Tutorial or things like that, there a tons of results.

[Cordova Documentation 5.0](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/)

**PLUGINS IN CORDOVA**

Cordova wouldn't be as well known as it is, if there were not those great plugins. The list of plugins is nearly endless and from day to day there are new ones.

You can install a plugin via terminal.

1. cd yourProject
2. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-pluginName
   where `pluginName` would be the name of that plugin. For example: console
3. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console

After you added such a plugin to your project, you're going to run the build command (`cordova build` - integrate the "*plugin add process*" inside your normal way of building an application.

So now after you added the plugin you want to, you can use the commands the plugin brings with. But attention: You have to wait for the `deviceReady` event, before you can use your plugins.

**Example for the DeviceReady Event**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use device APIs
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

You can find detailed information about that event and all the other events inside the [cordova events docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html).

Comment: I agree that sigle page application is the best choice, but I don't think this answers the question he made

Comment: He asked "How to redirect from one page to another page" - this is, what my answer is about. The Topic "plugins" is a very specific one on its own but i'm going to edit my answer and provide some details about that also.

Comment: @jcesarmobile Exactly, Because need to call Webservices and it is not like sample app it includes some many pages.

Comment: @Sithys My above code is working good but when I'm generating .apk file it is working like web application, not like Cordova application.

Comment: Than provide a full code snippet or should i guess where to look for your mistake? Who is building a "native feel" phonegap cordova application with `window.open(),window.location.href() and window.location.replace().` Man, just google and take a deeper look into the whole sing. Keywords would be also angularJS, ionic and so on.